# TortoiseSVN does not recognize svn folders after upgrading to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, tortoisesvn

I have upgraded my computer from Windows XP to Windows 8 and opted to keep all my files and settings. After the upgrade I installed TortoiseSVN version 1.710, which was the version that I also used while still on XP. But now it no longer seems to recognize the SVN folders. On my folders I  have no overlay icons, and when I right-click I only get the 'checkout' option as if the folder was empty or does not contain any version control. 
When I select 'Show hidden files' in explorer I can see that the _svn folder is definitely there. I do notice it is marked 'read only' but removing that does not solve the issue.
Does anyone has an idea as to why Tortoise does not detect the _svn folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the question. From version 1.6 Tortoise no longer recognizes the _svn folder but uses .svn folders instead. On my Windows XP machine I probably once opted to install the 'hack' that allowed for using the _svn folders and it stayed that way even when I upgraded to 1.7.
Since the upgrade to Windows 8 kept the files but required a fresh install of all software, the option to use _svn folders was lost. 
So I had to find a solution to rename all my _svn folders to .svn. Fortunately windows 8 comes with Powershell 3.0 which makes this easy.
Just open the Powershell window, change your directory to the 'Documents' folder and type:

```
Get-ChildItem _svn -recurse -force | foreach {rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_",".")}
```

This will rename all _svn folders, and all is solved.

Comment: Not only do you have to address the _svn hack, SVN 1.7 will not immediately recognize a pre-1.7 working copy beyond knowing that it might be a WC - you need to run `SVN Upgrade` at the top level of each WC.

Comment: @alroc : True. But I already did that once for all folders. Which is the reason I'm quite sure I was already version 1.7 under Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Is it '_svn' or '.svn'? And do newly checked-out projects work for you?

My guess is that the upgrade somehow renamed the folder from '.svn' to '_svn', leaving Tortoise unable to pick it up. In that case, you'd have to rename them and it should work again.

I've been running TortoiseSVN on Win8 in the past without problems.