# i cannot see tortoise svn items in context menu in windows explorer under windows 8 - 64 bit

Tags: svn, windows-8, tortoisesvn, 64-bit, windows-explorer

I installed it twice (and restart windows after each installation)
I also tried with 32 bit version, but the result was the same

Comment: Look this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360587/tortoisesvn-does-not-recognize-svn-folders-after-upgrading-to-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit version of Tortoise SVN will not work with the 64-bit (default) Windows Explorer at all. Are you *certain* that you've installed the 64-bit version?

The linked topic is only applicable if your working copies aren't being recognized. Are you getting *any* TSVN context menus? What folders are you attempting to use it with?

Comment: i've tried both versions (32/64 bit). After couple of deinstall/reinstall it works now, but i do not know why :(